# Diagnostic of debian packages?

Tags: debian

Will this command do a diagnostic of the packages ?

```
dpkg-query --showformat='${Package}__${Version}__${Status}\n' --show | grep -v "ok installed"
```

Answer (score 1):

Sort of. It will list all packages that are in a state other than "fully installed and configured" or "never installed or completely purged from the system". So it will list any packages whose installation has been interrupted or whose configuration has failed.

However, it will also list all packages which you have removed but have left the configuration files around (i.e. in `apt`/`apt-get`/`aptitude` lingo, packages you have *removed* but not *purged*).

Also note that this information is just based on the package's state as recorded by the package management system: it does not actually check that all the files provided by package(s) are present and unmodified or anything like that. If you want that kind of diagnostic, use `dpkg -V` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the diagnostic tool ; `check`:

```
apt-get check
```

`man apt-get`:

```
check
   check is a diagnostic tool; it updates the package cache and checks
   for broken dependencies.
```